# Data integration using SQL statements, opposed to cursors/triggers

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, cursor, data-integration

I am integrating my .NET/SQL application with two other products. Having read/experienced the performance and other issues with cursors and triggers, I decided to use the batch method using a series of SQL insert and update statements. In some places I need to look up mapping IDs from the incoming feeds and map to IDs in my system. I also need to do a fair amount of error handling in my sql batch code where for instance if a related ID is missing or NULL, I write that to an error log and not process that record at all. I think the system will process a large initial batch of hundreds/thousands of records and once in production we will read incoming feeds on an hourly basis. So far so good.

The problem is I can't possibly pre-determine every single error that could result in the incoming feed. After days of testing I am still seeing something or the other fails and the batch doesn't process. When an error happens in a batch or set-based integration (rather than cursor/trigger), I have no way of pin pointing which record the statement failed at. I can figure out which SQL statement in my batch failed but not at which exact row.

Whereas if I used a cursor I would know as the cursor processes which exact record bombed and tuck it away into an error log. Isn't this one reason why in some cases cursors are helpful?

Also, is there any way using my current set-based method of batching, I could pin point which row insert/update failed and have it move on with the rest of the processing?

Thanks.

Comment: You are running each batch of INSERT/UPDATE statements as a transaction, right?
Like first 1000 rows out of 1.000.000, second 1000 rows out of 1.000.000, an so on?
When one batch fails, your application logic could retry processing just those failed 1000 (or whatever your batch size is) records in smaller batches or one by one. And mark the ones which repeatedly failed for manual investigation.

Comment: I guess I could do that. Thanks. The number of rows in this particular project is not that large so I did not batch them in transactions. In some tables there are thousands, but in others in the hundreds at the most. Which is why triggers and cursors were considered by the developer before me. In the end what I will do is just keep tweaking my code and filter all the error conditions out to a point where no batches fail.